# Laravel Eloquent relationship data retrieve

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have below code to get data from database,

```
 $profile = Profiles::find(1);
 $currency = Profiles::find($profile->currency_id)->currency;
```

Then created a relationship in the model as below,

```
class Profiles extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Profiles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'profile_id';

    public function Currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currencies::class, 'currency_id');
    }
}

class Currencies extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Currencies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'currency_id';

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profiles::class, 'currency_id');
    }
}
```

Problem is that there is only 1 profile and 100 currency, `currency_id` is a foreign key in `Profiles` table,

I could not get data and get this error, `Trying to get property 'currency' of non-object"`

If i use  `$currency = Profiles::find(1)->currency;` then it retrieve first row of `Curriencies` table which is not required data.

How can I get currency row for that specific profile?

Comment: Why do you pass id of currency to profile model? Here `Profiles::find($profile->currency_id)`?

Comment: $prof_data = Profiles::find(1);
$currencyAll = $pro_data->currency;

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI, because i am not clear what find will accept, if I pass 1, then it always find 1st row of Currencies table, profile have currency_id=53 and i need to get all details of currency_id=53 from ```Currencies``` table.

Comment: @jrcode you should pass id of Profile table to Profile class, not Currencies. It will fetch whole row for you

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI, do you mean by this? ```Restoprofiles::find($restoprofile->profile_id)->currency;``` as my profile_id = 1, it always return first row of ```Currencies```, in my profile there is ```currency_id``` with value of ```53``` that i need to retrieve from ```Currencies```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `find()` method will look for the `primaryKey` and in your second call the `currency_id` is not the pk.
Two solution for you:

- replace the find by a `where` clause like so:  `$currency = Profiles::where('currency_id',$profile->currency_id)->value('currency')`
- Or a more *Laravel way* to do it, through the relationship `$currency = $profile->currency;`

Comment: @mi59, will this retrieve data from Currencies table?, what I need is get the currency of id which is assigned to profile,

Comment: yes exactly, have a look to the doc to have more details about the `BelongTo` relationship https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse